# MongoDB shows error: version too new for this mongod

Tags: mongodb

I ran command `db.repairDatabase()`, and interrupted it and killed the mongo process.

When I try to start the `mongodb` service again, it won't start. When checking logs, I found:

```
targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2018-02-27T10:03:20.886+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.8 
2018-02-27T10:03:20.886+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0
2018-02-:[initandlisten] Fatal assertion 28579 UnsupportedFormat: Unable to find metadata for table:index-2-1248356723443587117 Index: {name: _id_, ns: energy_mgdb.m_meter} - version too new for this mongod. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.4-index-downgrade for detailed instructions on how to handle this error.
2018-02-27T10:03:21.700+0800 I -
```

Now, I can't even start the MongoDB service due to this error. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: To provide some more detail about what the error means: the collection `energy_mgdb.m_meter` seems to have been built when the deployment was on MongoDB 3.4; this version introduces a new index version which is not compatible with MongoDB 3.2 (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/#backwards-incompatible-features). The error indicates that the repairDatabase process was proceeding and encountered a index version it was not familiar with and had to stop.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried upgrading MongoDB to a newer version? There may be a fix or at least something that can handle this case (for example [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-25312)). I would try [version 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-standalone/) for now since it's better to upgrade one version at a time.